# ssh: connect to host ec2-xxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr, amazon-emr

I first list emr cluster:

```
✗ aws emr list-clusters
{
    "Clusters": [
        {
            "Id": "j-MQIKB378OARL",
            "Name": "Spark cluster",
            "Status": {
                "State": "WAITING",
                "StateChangeReason": {
                    "Message": "Cluster ready after last step failed."
                },
                "Timeline": {
                    "CreationDateTime": 1524200251.319,
                    "ReadyDateTime": 1524201100.225
                }
            },
            "NormalizedInstanceHours": 6
        },
```

Then I try to connect:

```
✗ aws emr ssh --cluster-id j-MQIKB378OARL --key-pair-file ~/.ssh/keys/key-pair.pem
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/keys/key-pair.pem hadoop@ec2-xxxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -t
ssh: connect to host ec2-xxxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: How does the security group look like?

Comment: @Mahdi if the port was not open in security group, the it would be `time-out`. Here, it seems that the service is not running on port 22 or is rejecting the connection, if firewall is configured.

Comment: @kintuparantu I was looking at: `AWS WAF and AWS Shield` I don't see I have any firewall defined, is this what you referred to?

Comment: @Mahdi I don't see any "security group" service in aws, this is what I see: "Security, Identity & Compliance
IAM
Cognito
Secrets Manager
GuardDuty
Inspector
Amazon Macie
AWS Single Sign-On
Certificate Manager
CloudHSM
Directory Service
WAF & Shield
Artifact"

Comment: Security groups are in the VPC service, but probably easier to find the one you're looking for from EC2. Look in the web console.

Comment: Can you check the status of the backing instance in AWS Web Console?

Comment: I see that "Security Group" name for the instances is called "ElasticMapReduce-master" or "ElasticMapReduce-slave" and when clicking on it i see: "SSH
TCP
22
212.179.50.200/32"

Comment: @TarunLalwani when I look at the status of the backing instance in aws web console in EC2 I see: something similar to all instances: `i-00fade6b28b1a53b2
c1.medium
us-east-1d
 running
 2/2 checks passed
None
ec2-107-23-133-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com
107.23.133.93
-
my-key-pair
disabled
April 29, 2018 at 10:30:14 AM UTC+3
ElasticMapReduce-slave`

Comment: Is the disabled against the `key-pair` may be the cluster is getting created with no keypair to access it with for higher security?

Comment: @TarunLalwani The `disabled` is for `monitoring` header.  I tried create a new instance (not EMR) to verify I can ssh with my-key-pair and all was fine, but if I create an EMR cluster cannot ssh.  The key pair is the `mt-key-pair` so I do have one in EMR...

Comment: Have you tried `telnet <publicdns> 22` on the master node manually? See what happens there. Also normally should get a message `"Message": "Waiting after step completed"` and yours is `"Message": "Cluster ready after last step failed."`, which may indicate something is wrong

Comment: telnet ec2-34-200-219-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com  22
Trying 34.200.219.57...
telnet: connect to address 34.200.219.57: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: in addition in the events I see:

"Amazon EMR cluster j-3JZSVX31KXRZR (My cluster) was requested at 2018-04-29 06:48 UTC and is being created."

"Step s-3334BDBBED6ZB (Setup hadoop debugging) in Amazon EMR cluster j-3JZSVX31KXRZR (My cluster) started running at 2018-04-29 07:10 UTC."

"Amazon EMR cluster j-3JZSVX31KXRZR (My cluster) began running steps at 2018-04-29 07:10 UTC."

Comment: "
"Step s-3334BDBBED6ZB (Setup hadoop debugging) in Amazon EMR cluster j-3JZSVX31KXRZR (My cluster) completed execution at 2018-04-29 07:10 UTC. The step started running at 2018-04-29 07:10 UTC and took 0 minutes to complete."

"Amazon EMR cluster j-3JZSVX31KXRZR (My cluster) finished running all pending steps at 2018-04-29 07:10 UTC."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the security group of your instance does not allow incoming ssh traffic.

From [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

> Security groups enable you to control traffic to your instance,
>   including the kind of traffic that can reach your instance. For
>   example, you can allow computers from only your home network to access
>   your instance using SSH. If your instance is a web server, you can
>   allow all IP addresses to access your instance using HTTP or HTTPS, so
>   that external users can browse the content on your web server.

To add a rule to a security group for inbound SSH traffic over IPv4 using the console:

1. In the navigation pane of the Amazon EC2 console, choose Instances. Select your instance and look at the Description tab; Security groups lists the security groups that are associated with the instance. Choose view rules to display a list of the rules that are in effect for the instance.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups. Select one of the security groups associated with your instance.
3. In the details pane, on the Inbound tab, choose Edit. In the dialog, choose Add Rule, and then choose SSH from the Type list.
4. In the Source field, choose My IP to automatically populate the field with the public IPv4 address of your local computer. Alternatively, choose Custom and specify the public IPv4 address of your computer or network in CIDR notation. For example, if your IPv4 address is 203.0.113.25, specify 203.0.113.25/32 to list this single IPv4 address in CIDR notation. If your company allocates addresses from a range, specify the entire range, such as 203.0.113.0/24.
5. Choose Save.

Comment: comprehensive answer, I will just add that I already had the "ssh" rule so I didn't need to add it, I just needed to change the source IP as apparently, it was created with an incorrect ip.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit security group `ElasticMapReduce-...`
2. Edit source ip for port 22
3. It was incorrect
4. Update to either your source ip or anywhere.

Comment: Was the source IP set to the IP from where you created the cluster?